# Trying to automate date filling using R Selenium but sendKeyToElements() is not working

Tags: javascript, r, xml-parsing, rselenium

I am trying to get the AQI data for a year from (app.cpcbccr.com/AQI_India/). For that i was trying to send single date element first  using R Selenium. I am able to click on the date box using clickElement() but   i am not able to clear element(clearElement()) and sendKeyToElements().

```
    library(RSelenium)
    library(tidyverse)
    driver <- rsDriver(browser=c("chrome"),port=4444L,chromever="83.0.4103.39")
             remote_driver <- driver[["client"]]
             remote_driver$navigate("https://app.cpcbccr.com/AQI_India/")
                      date_element <- remote_driver$findElement(using = 'id', value="date")
                      date_element$clickElement()                                                    
                      date_element$clearElement()                                                  
                      date_element$sendKeysToElement(list("24/08/2020"))
```

It doesnt show any error but the last two commands are not executed on the controlled browser.